How to catch failed rows during the bulk_create in Django?
I process large CSV, Excel files and save result using Django bulk_create method.
But some of rows may have corrupted data and in that case all rows will not be saved to database.
Ideally I want to catch failed rows and show users which rows are failed to save.
Then users can make decision whether skip failed rows or upload new file.
I try to catch failed rows during the bulk_create in Django.

The bulk_create method doesn't provide built-in functionality to catch and handle errors on a per-row basis; if any row fails, the entire bulk operation is rolled back. You have to process the file in chunks, validate each row.

Is there any elegant way to catch failed rows?
